# How do I stop LibreOffice from removing forward slashes around text and making that text italic?

Tags: libreoffice

When I type in LibreOffice:

```
/usr/dirk/documents
```

it is shown on the screen as

```
usrdirk/documents
```

The forward slashes around `usr` are gone, `usr` is shown in italics.
Any idea which setting I have to make to get this working properly ?

Comment: See https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/a-word-that-is-between-two-slashes-italic/33704

Comment: Thanks ! That is the solution.

Comment: Note that, if you think the "slashes to convert to italics" shortcut is otherwise useful for you in general, you can "undo" the conversion in this particular instance by pressing the 'undo' shortcut (typically Ctrl-Z) right after the autoconversion is performed. This is true for _all_ autoconversions (including capitalizations, etc)

Comment: Efcharisto Taso !

Answer (score 38):

- [Tools](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/swriter/guide/auto_off.html) > AutoCorrect > AutoCorrect Options
- Deselect option Automatic bold, /italic/, -strikeout- and underline

Comment: Thanks ! that is the setting I was looking for

Comment: @Dirk in that case award the answer with the green checkmark :)

Comment: MSWord has (or used to?) give the opportunity to hit backspace to reject an unintended autocorrect. Does LO have something similar?